# How to modify attribute 'value' content in playwright - angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, playwright

I am wondering if someone could give an idea how to access and change the content of value attribute in the code below.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id_1" name="test_name_1" value="John"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id_2" name="test_n_2" value="Student"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Verified with: `expect(await page.locator('td:has-text("John")')).toBeTruthy();`

How do I change the value in td -> input, that is, `value="John" => value="Paul"` and `value="Student" => value="Teacher"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your assertion is broken--it always passes because it's testing whether Playwright locator objects are truthy (`page.locator()` doesn't return a promise, so awaiting it doesn't do anything). Always make your tests fail (for example, by removing the element from the page), then make them pass (by re-adding the element), to ensure that there's no false positives and the test is testing what you think it is. Also, generally use [web first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions), which would help avoid this sort of mistake.

`toBeTruthy()` is generally too broad for most assertions. It'd be better to use `toHaveValue()` since that's precisely the condition you want to test, so it better communicates your intent and makes the failure error message more comprehensible. This also helps avoid false positives.

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `::the HTML from your post::`;

test('has a name="test_name_1" input with value "John"', async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(page.locator('td input[name="test_name_1"]')).toHaveValue("John");
});
```

To fill it, you can use `.fill()`:

```js
test('can change value of name="test_name_1" input', async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const input = page.locator('td input[name="test_name_1"]');
  await input.fill("whatever");
  await expect(input).toHaveValue("whatever");
});
```